# categorical labels using cross entropy loss, accuracy does not change | deep learning pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I have a question concerning my recent project.

I have been trying using `PyTorch` to train my multiclass-classification work. I have `3` labels (namely, `0` -> none, `1` -> left, `2` -> right) in my image dataset. I have used `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` as my loss function and `Adam` as optimizer. However, the training result looks like this, the accuracy does not change at all.

```
==> Building new CNN model ...
==> Initialize CUDA support for CNN model ...
==> Preparing RcCar Image dataset ...
==> Start training ...
Iteration: 1 | Loss: 1.3453235626220703 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
==> Saving model ...
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py:251: UserWarning: Couldn't retrieve source code for container of type SimpleCNN. It won't be checked for correctness upon loading.
  "type " + obj.__name__ + ". It won't be checked "
Iteration: 2 | Loss: 0.9048898816108704 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 3 | Loss: 0.873579740524292 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 4 | Loss: 0.8702362179756165 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 5 | Loss: 0.8713874220848083 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 6 | Loss: 0.8639134168624878 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 7 | Loss: 0.8590883612632751 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 8 | Loss: 0.8576076626777649 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 9 | Loss: 0.8523686528205872 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
Iteration: 10 | Loss: 0.8462777137756348 | Training accuracy: 70% | Test accuracy: 43%
```

I am thinking whether this is because the loss function I chose is not suitable or I have to one-hot encode the labels into

```
[
[0,0,1],
[0,1,0],
...
]
```

like this.

I have enclosed my custom Dataset part. Please, please, please help me with this. Thank you!

```py
def RcCarImageLoader(root, batch_size_train, batch_size_test):
    """
    RC Car Image Loader.
    Args:
        train_root:
        test_root:
        batch_size_train:
        batch_size_test:
    Return:
        train_loader:
        test_loader:
    """

    # Normalize training set together with augmentation
    transform_train = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(64),
        transforms.RandomRotation(10),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

    # Normalize test set same as training set without augmentation
    transform_test = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(64),
        transforms.CenterCrop(64),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

    # Loading Tiny ImageNet dataset
    print("==> Preparing RcCar Image dataset ...")

    train_set = ImageLoader(csv_filename="./train.csv", transform=transform_train)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_set, batch_size=batch_size_train, num_workers=2)

    test_set = ImageLoader(csv_filename="./test.csv", transform=transform_test, train=False)
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        test_set, batch_size=batch_size_test, num_workers=2)

    return train_loader, test_loader



def image_loader(path):
    """Image Loader helper function."""
    return Image.open(path.rstrip("\n")).convert('RGB')


class ImageLoader(Dataset):
    """Image Loader for Tiny ImageNet."""

    def __init__(self, csv_filename, transform=None, train=True, loader=image_loader):
        """
        Image Loader Builder.
        Args:
            base_path: path to triplets.txt
            filenames_filename: text file with each line containing the path to an image e.g., `images/class1/sample.JPEG`
            triplets_filename: A text file with each line containing three images
            transform: torchvision.transforms
            loader: loader for each image
        """
        self.transform = transform
        self.loader = loader

        self.train_flag = train

        # load training data
        if self.train_flag:
            train_data = []


            csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv_filename)
            self.train_label = np.asarray(csv_file.iloc[:, 1])
            train_img_names = np.asarray(csv_file.iloc[:, 0])

            for train_img_name in train_img_names:
                train_img = self.loader(os.path.join("./train/", train_img_name))
                train_data.append(train_img)
            self.train_data = train_data

            # train_label_one_hot = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(len(train_label))]
            # for i, row in enumerate(train_label_one_hot):
            #     row[train_label[i]] = 1
            #
            # self.train_label = np.asarray(train_label_one_hot)


        # load test data
        else:
            test_data = []

            csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv_filename)
            self.test_label = np.asarray(csv_file.iloc[:, 1])
            test_img_names = np.asarray(csv_file.iloc[:, 0])

            for test_img_name in test_img_names:
                test_img = self.loader(os.path.join("./test/", test_img_name))
                test_data.append(test_img)
            self.test_data = test_data


            # test_label_one_hot = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(len(test_label))]
            # for i, row in enumerate(test_label_one_hot):
            #     row[test_label[i]] = 1
            #
            # self.test_label = np.asarray(test_label_one_hot)


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        """Get image and label in dataset."""
        # get training images

        if self.train_flag:
            img = self.train_data[index]
            label = self.train_label[index]
            if self.transform is not None:
                img = self.transform(img)

            return (img, label)

        else:
            img = self.test_data[index]
            label = self.test_label[index]
            if self.transform is not None:
                img = self.transform(img)

            return (img, label)


    def __len__(self):
        if self.train_flag:
            return len(self.train_label)
        else:
            return len(self.test_label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your speculations about the loss function and one-hot encoding are correct. Do one-hot encoding and use [BCEloss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bceloss) and let me know.